# Wordfence detects change in wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php

Tags: security

I moved my site from hosting provider A and domain name B to hosting provider X and domain name Y. I had Wordfence in the old site. I just installed it in the new site and ran a scan. Wordfence found the following change in wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php :

```
279    @wp_mail($email, __('New WordPress Site'), $message);
```

became

```
279    //@wp_mail($email, __('New WordPress Site'), $message);
```

Anybody knows is this indicates some hack or security issue?

Answer (score 3):

Search the Trac for these kinds of core changes:

- [trac ticket #23291](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23291) and
- [trac ticket #23291.2.diff](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/23291/23291.2.diff)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this also. According to WordFence,

> It looks like someone disabled email sending in that file. It doesn’t look malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Same. It happens when you do a move. All of mine came back with that pick up along with edits to the version.php file and a change in DNS settings. You are ok.